# Fire click event in ionic cordova on ios 11.2.x doesn't work

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an app using ionic.
I have a button to open file browser :

HTML page :

```
<input class="input-file" name="imgToUpload" id="imgToUpload" type="file"
         #imgToUpload  [(ngModel)]="message.file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
    <div ion-button block large (click)="openFileBrowser($event)" style="background-color:#39D2B4;">
      <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    </div>
```

In my .ts file I have the method openFileBrowser :

```
openFileBrowser(event:any){
event.preventDefault();
let element : HTMLElement = document.getElementById('imgToUpload') as HTMLElement;
element.click();}
```

Before updating iOS 11.2.6 this method was fired without problem.
Since iOS 11.2.6, click() did'nt fired.

Has anyone encountered this problem?
How can I solve it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this way, with a div simulating a button:

```
<div class="fileUpload" ion-button>
  <input class="upload" type="file" (change)="selectImagem($event)" multiple accept="image/*"/>
</div>
```

And in the css, i hide the input file

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #488aff;
    box-shadow: none;

    input.upload {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
  }
```